# How to use css classes with Booststrap and wagtail

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, wagtail

I am using a Bootstrap theme and in one particular location I want to place up to three cards horizontally on the page. I have the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">{{ self.title }}</h1>
    <div class="card_deck;" style="display: table;">
        {% for card in self.cards %}    
            <div class="card;" style="display: table-cell; padding:20px;">
                A card goes here
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two questions related to this:

1. How do I centre the cards on the page?
2. What is the best way to handle the css? I clearly don't want to mess with the Bootstrap card and card_deck elements, so is the only solution to leave the style in the div tag?

Comment: by using `display: table` and `table-cell` you are already ' messing ' with bootstrap because bootstrap uses flex elements. To use bootstrap try looking at their examples. Use class `row` for `card_deck`  and use `col-4` on the `card` elements.

Comment: put your css in an external css file included after the bootstrap files, that way any overrides are separate to bootstrap and won't ruin your upgrade path. Also unrelated to your question - the semicolons in your classes are invalid

Comment: @MihaiT Thank you. This is what I needed. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @Pete Thanks. Semi-colons sorted :)

Comment: @MihaiT col-4 assumes three cards. I want to have up to 3, so what should I do if there are only 2 cards?

Comment: Bootstrap uses a 12 'sections' grid. So if you have 2 columns you have `col-6`. 6 is from 12/2 . So you could use a class on `card`  equal to `col-12/self.cards.length` . Which means that if you have 3 cards you will have col-4 , if you have 4 cards you will have `col-3` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

for
1. Center the card on the page

```
<div align='center' class='row'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      then paste the cards in here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      then paste the cards in here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      then paste the cards in here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. You can simply add new class to it, for example, assuming the div below is the place I want to add the CSS

   then paste the cards in here

   then go ahead and style as such
   .myNewCss{
   style here
   }

Comment: `align`  HTML attribute is not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your cards to have bootstrap classes depending on how many cards you have you could use a class on card equal to `col-12/self.cards.length`. This is because bootstrap uses a 12 'sections' grid. So if you have 2 columns you have col-6. 6 is from 12/2 . Which means that if you have 3 cards you will have col-4 , if you have 4 cards you will have col-3 and so on.

I made a pure javascript example below which approximately reproduces what you want to achieve

```js
const cards = [{
  text: 'card1 text'
}, {
  text: 'card2 text'
}, {
  text: 'card3 text'
}]

const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
card.forEach((c, i) => {
  c.classList.add(`col-${12/cards.length}`)
  c.innerHTML = cards[i].text
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">{{ self.title }}</h1>
  <div class="card_deck row">

    <div class="card" style="padding:20px;">

    </div>
    <div class="card" style="padding:20px;">

    </div>
    <div class="card" style="padding:20px;">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```